# Why mysql deadlock happened for select for update and insert?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee, database-deadlocks

I use peewee and mysql wrote a simple lock class. The acquire method sometimes will throw DeadLock Exception.

Here is the output of innodb status monitoring and code.

1. Seems first transaction is waiting a lock and hold nothing. So why can deadlock happen if it not holding anything transaction two needed?
2. It seems the select for update and insert statement will lock each other. But I still do not understand why. can you help to illustrate?

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-01-18 13:40:37 0x7f565a5bc700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4137600947, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`business_type`, `t1`.`resource`, `t1`.`owner`, `t1`.`timeout`, `t1`.`comment`, `t1`.`gmt_created`, `t1`.`gmt_modified` FROM `resource_((`t1`.`resource` = 'r') AND (`t1`.`business_type` = 't')) AND ((`t1`.`owner` = '119909') OR ((`t1`.`timeout` != 0) AND ((to_seconds('2022-01-18 13:40:37.3448`.`gmt_modified`)) > `t1`.`timeout`)))) LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0 FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 255733 page no 5 n bits 72 index lock_business_type_resource of table `database_name`.`resource_lock` trx id 4137600947 lock_mode X lociting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 74; asc t;;
 1: len 1; hex 72; asc r;;
 2: len 4; hex 800036f5; asc   6 ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4137600943, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
INSERT INTO `resource_lock` (`business_type`, `resource`, `owner`, `timeout`) VALUES ('t', 'r', '120048', 1)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 255733 page no 5 n bits 72 index lock_business_type_resource of table `database_name`.`resource_lock` trx id 4137600943 lock_mode X loc
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 74; asc t;;
 1: len 1; hex 72; asc r;;
 2: len 4; hex 800036f5; asc   6 ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 255733 page no 5 n bits 72 index lock_business_type_resource of table `database_name`.`resource_lock` trx id 4137600943 lock mode S wai
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 74; asc t;;
 1: len 1; hex 72; asc r;;
 2: len 4; hex 800036f5; asc   6 ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

```
# coding=utf-8
import datetime
import logging
import peewee
from peewee import fn
from peewee import Model, CharField, IntegerField, DateTimeField, SQL
from peewee import MySQLDatabase


db_info = {}  # mysql database address port user and password
database = MySQLDatabase(db_info)  # db connection


class Lock(Model):
    # below two row have unique index 

    business_type = CharField(null=False)
    resource = CharField(null=False)
    owner = CharField(null=False)
    timeout = IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    comment = CharField(null=True)
    gmt_created = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")])
    gmt_modified = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")])

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('business_type', 'resource'), True),
        )
        table_name = 'resource_lock'
        database = database



def acquire(owner, timeout):

    with database.atomic():

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
            # two case that the lock can be selected
            # 1. current process is the owner
            # 2. lock timeout
            # but the select statement here may hit deadlock occasionally.
            # db deadlock should meas two sessions holding a row/lock
            # and waiting for each other. but here we have
            # unique constraint on resource and business_type. Only one row should be involved
            lock = Lock.select().where(
                Lock.resource == 'r',
                Lock.business_type == 't',
                ((Lock.owner == owner) | (Lock.timeout != 0) & (fn.to_seconds(now) - fn.to_seconds(Lock.gmt_modified) > Lock.timeout))
            ).for_update().get()
            if str(lock.owner) == (owner):
                print 'select success {} {}'.format(owner, time.time())
            else:
                print 'select success timeout, lock_owner: {}, owner: {} {}'.format(lock.owner, owner, time.time())
            lock.timeout = timeout
            lock.gmt_created = now
            lock.gmt_modified = now
            lock.owner = owner
            lock.save()
            print 'select success {}'.format(owner)
            return True
        except Lock.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        # if lock not exist "Lock.DoesNotExist" multiple processes can create the lock at same time. Only one
        # can succeeded. Others hit peewee.IntegrityError and acquire fail because of unique index
        try:
            Lock.create(business_type='t', resource='r', owner=owner, timeout=timeout)
            print 'create success {} {}'.format(owner, time.time())
            return True
        except peewee.IntegrityError:
            print 'create fail {} {}'.format(owner, time.time())
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.choice([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]))
        acquire(owner=os.getpid(), timeout=1)
```

Comment: You need to check the output of innodb status monitor to understand what is causing the deadlock

Comment: There are multiple errors in to_seconds('2022-01-18 13:40:37.3448`.`gmt_modified`) -- please check the source.  (Note apostrophe vs backtic; time-dot-column).  If you can get the actual query, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

If there really is an `OR` in that query, I suggest you do one of these:

- Get rid of the `OR` and build an equivalent query using `UNION`, then figure out the optimal indexes.
- Split the query into two `SELECTs`, then build a separate transaction for each.